How did prime Spock appear in “Into Darkness?”
In Star Trek: Beyond, I seem to remember that older 'prime Spock' (Nimoy) dies and it causes the younger alt Spock (Quinto) to almost leave Starfleet.
Yer during the 3rd film, Into Darkness, alt Spock contacts prime Spock to discuss Khan.
Has it been explained how that is possible given that in the timeline of the JJ films the time traveling prime Spock died in the previous movie?

You have the order of the movies backwards.  Star Trek Into Darkness was the second film in the reboot timeline, not the third; it came out in 2013, while Star Trek Beyond came out in 2016.
